# React Date Range from rsuite

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am importing react-date-range from rsuite and also import 'rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-default.css'; Following is my code snippet:

```
import {DateRangePicker} from 'rsuite'
import 'react-daterange-picker/dist/css/react-calendar.css'
import 'rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-default.css';

<div className="dates">
     <DateRangePicker/>
</div>
```

Problem:
I am using this along with other elements. But whenever I am using

```
import 'rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-default.css';
```

Other elements in the dom as well as the `DateRangePicker` element itself is not showing. But when I comment out the `..default.css`, everything shows but the DateRangePicker doesn't function or toggle down. I have attached a picture that doesn't show any element in the dashboard because of the import of `default.css`

[image]

Comment: Try to change your imports sequence: first import 'rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-default.css' than 'react-daterange-picker/dist/css/react-calendar.css'

Comment: still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error by importing this library. It is resolved by using below:

```
.fade {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```